# Vulnerability to Meltdown and Spectre?

Tags: security, vulnerability

Being a distributed computing platform, is Ethereum vulnerable to Meltdown and Spectre attacks?

Answer (score 2):

No.  At least not as far as the EVM and contracts are concerned.  The EVM has too much overhead and lacks the constructs needed to exploit either of these bugs.

Comment: As far as I understand, even JavaScript can be used to exploit these vulnerabilities. Could you explain in more detail why it should be impossible via the EVM?

Comment: You can use javascript to exploit these vulnerabilities because you have the ability to run high-performance code in javascript, and can do high-resolution timing to determine whether or not some piece of memory was fetched from cache or not.  The EVM doesn't provide these capabilities--it's slow, lacks high-resolution timing, etc